# XSLT Performance Issue with large xml data

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have used XSLT to show XML data. I have used templates and there is no any for-each logic. Now with large xml data, it takes very long time to show in browser. Following are the details related to xml:
9 columns
10000 rows

In IE9, it takes 20-24 seconds to show all records. Until all records are not transformed, IE show nothing on screen.

How can I fix this performance related issues?

Thank you,
Regards,
Kaushal Kumar

Comment: Even if you don't use `<xsl:for-each` the run times implicitly caused by template matching can be enormous. We need to see the relevant excerpts of your XSLT to be able to help. Often, XSLT templates can be sped up quite substantially using indexes.

Comment: I agree with Marcus, the answers to your question would be more helpful if you showed the XSLT code.

Comment: With performance, with XSLT as with any other technology, the devil is in the detail, and no-one can solve a performance problem without seeing the detail. It would be useful to investigate whether other XSLT engines give similar results.

Comment: I would also question the business implementation of showing 10,000 table rows in a browser. perhaps you would be better served to revisit whether anyone is actually reading or using 10,000 rows in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound all that slow to me if this is on the client side.

The problem is that it won't render progressively since it needs all the XML and all the XSL before it can transform.

I would suggest doing the transform on the server side and serve it up as html to the client.

Comment: Perhaps one could add that this will eventually change with XSLT 3.0 where streaming is an integral part of the specification?

Comment: Streaming might improve latency but it won't improve overall speed. And I don't think we'll ever see it implemented browser-side.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using IE (and in general, too), I suggest you have a look at the **Write Efficient XSLT** section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647804.aspx#scalenetchaptch09%20_topic12

Note that it says nothing about not using *for-each*.